# How does this work - Java 8 Optional.of and Optional.ofNullable

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have question with Java 8 Optionals.

The below code gives compilation error:

```
Integer number = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10));
```

But when we do the following it does **not**, I don't understand how this is working:

```
Integer number = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10)).orElse(10);
```

If we look at the documentation of [`Optional.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-), it returns an object of the type `static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value)` which signifies that it is internally type casting, but the documentation says it return type is `Optional`.

I get that the `.orElse` method return type is `T` which would work fine *if* it goes to `orElse` condition, i.e in case the passed in object is `null`, but if it is not null how does it typecast it?

Comment: Think of it as if `Optional.orElse()` was called `Optional.getOrElse()` (which it should, IMHO). And while you're at it, think of `Optional.get()` as if it was called `Optional.getOrThrow()`.

Comment: *but if it is not null how does it typecast it?* being the actual question seems strange on what answer is accepted since all the existing answers elaborate on the usage of `ofNullable` and `orElse` but not about the typecast! A simpler answer could be if it's not null it uses the type `new Integer` specified by you, if it is null(i don't see how) it works the same way `Integer i = 10;` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the declaration of the method,

```
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value)
```

So this takes T and returns `Optional<T>` So in your case it takes `Integer` and returns an `Optional<Integer>`

So when you do this,

```
Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10)).orElse(10);
```

The `orElse` call will unwrap the optional and returns the value in it if it is not empty. Otherwise it merely returns the given value.

**Update**

As per the following comments you can simplify it further while leaving the job to the Autoboxing.

```
Optional.ofNullable(10).orElse(10);
```

Comment: Exact answer! :)

Comment: Thanks got it , it would not short-circuit , i thought it would directly return from the .ofNullableMethod .

Comment: @user3792861 `ofNullable` is a factory method that construct an `Optional`, no unwrapping here.

Comment: Besides that, you should never write `new Integer(10)`. You can simply write `10` to let the autoboxing do its work, but when you really need to do it explicitly, use `Integer.valueOf(10)`. Starting with Java 9, the constructor used in `new Integer(10)` is marked *deprecated*.

Comment: Good catch indeed.

Comment: @Holger I really don't sense a possibility of `new Integer(<value>)` to be `null`, then does it not make sense to simply use `Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(10)).get()` in the current scenario? I couldn't see the compiler complaining over a check for `isPresent` there either.

Comment: @nullpointer the examples look artificial to me anyway, but yes, to get an `Optional<Integer>` the straight-forward way is `Optional.of(10)`. To get the `Integer`, just use `10`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it would be

```
Optional<Integer> numberOpt = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer number = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10));
```

With this you are try to put an `Optional<Integer`> to an `Integer`. Which is obviously not allowed.

When you do

```
Integer number = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10)).orElse(10);
```

With you are invoking `Optional<Integer>.orElse` and since you are not using `Optional<Integer>.get` this returns an `Integer`. So no errors.

Comment: Yes i know we can solve it using 
`Optional<Integer> number = Optional.ofNullable(new Integer(10));`

My question is about the second case why doesn't it throw error

Answer (score 0):

> I get that the .orElse method return type is T which would work fine
>   if it goes to orElse condition, i.e in case the passed in object is
>   null, but if it is not null how does it typecast it?

Optional.ofNullable() will return the Optional Object which will hold the actual value we have passed in as a parameter into into instance variable called value.

**orElse(T other)** - Return the value if present, otherwise returns the object passed as a parameter. Internals of orElse() method in Java 8 Optional class.

```
public T orElse(T other) {
   return value != null ? value : other;
}
```

orElse takes the parameter which is Generics and the type casting is performed implicitly. orElse will return the value if its not null otherwise returns the other value which was passed as an parameter.